# ruby each_line get the next line

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have a file with some duplicate entries. It looks like

```
Los Angeles, 6
Los Angeles, 6 
New York, 31
New York, 31
New YOrk, 31
.
.
.
```

Now I want to get rid of the duplicate data. What I try to do is to use each_line, see if the line equals to the next line, if they are the same then just skip, and write to a new file. The problem is how should I get the next line of that file? 
Or any other suggestions to do this?

Comment: are duplicates always consecutive?

Comment: Have you written any code? We'd like to see it because fixing your code is a lot easier than writing something from scratch and helping you integrate it. Also, if you're on Linux, look at the `uniq` command. From its man page: `Filter adjacent matching lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing against the next line is unnecessary, since you can easily see if the current line matches the previous one:

```
file = File.open("filename", "r")
previous_line = nil
file.each_line { |line|
   if line == previous_line
     # duplicate line; ignore
   else
     # different; do whatever you want
   end

   # remember this line so we can compare against it
   previous_line = line
}
```

Comment: Rather than opening and storing the file handle, then iterating using `each_line`, do it the Ruby way, and use `File.foreach`.

Answer (score 3):

If the duplicates are always consecutive, willglynn's solution works. Otherwise, I think the best way is to throw them into a hash.

```
unique_list = {}

File.foreach(filename) do |line|
  unique_list[line] = 1
end

unique_list.each do |line|
  new_file.print line
end
```

Comment: Firstly, I get this. uniq.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `filename' for main:Object (NameError).

Comment: Then after errors are fixed, I get this output...  "Los Angeles, 6\n", 1]["Los Angeles, 6 \n", 1]["New York, 31\n", 1]["New YOrk, 31\n", 1]

Comment: I posted an answer below which builds on @Anthony's answer here.

Answer (score 2):

If repeated lines are consecutive, you can write:

```
lines = open("file.txt").each_line.chunk(&:downcase).lazy.map { |s, ss| ss.first }
```

Substitute `downcase` for the function by which you decide which strings are equivalent.

Comment: As a word of warning, this isn't a scalable solution. Large files will be pulled into memory before being able to do anything with them.

Comment: @theTinMan: Updated to lazy enumerables (Ruby >= 2.1), it should be scalable now.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do this from shell instead of with Ruby, and you are working in *nix, it gets easier.  There's a *nix tool called [uniq](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/uniq.1.php) that is made for this.

Given your sample input, in file *input.txt*:

```
Los Angeles, 6
Los Angeles, 6
New York, 31
New York, 31
New YOrk, 31
```

Then this command will remove adjacent duplicates and print the result to standard-out:

```
$ uniq input.txt
Los Angeles, 6
New York, 31
New YOrk, 31
```

You will notice that the typo in the third instance of "New York" caused it to not be recognized as a duplicate.

To send the result to another file:

```
$ uniq input.txt >output.txt
$ cat output.txt
Los Angeles, 6
New York, 31
New YOrk, 31
```

To modify the original file, you can't redirect the output of uniq to it--you would be clobbering the input that uniq is reading.  Instead, use a temporary file:

```
$ uniq input.txt >input.txt.tmp && cp input.txt.tmp input.txt
$ cat input.txt
Los Angeles, 6
New York, 31
New YOrk, 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Anthony's answer. My idea is:

```
unique_list = {}
new_file=File.open('file2', "w")

File.foreach('filename') do |line|
  unique_list[line] = 1
end

unique_list.each do |key,value|
  new_file.puts key
end
```

Each line becomes the key of the hash with a value of 1. The keys are unique so a duplicate simply overwrites the last one.

The output, after ensuring no extra spaces on the end of the input strings is..

```
Los Angeles, 6
New York, 31
New YOrk, 31
```